# Кодировка кириллических символов в Telegram

Tags: php, utf-8, telegram-bot, telegram

Ребят, нужна помощь, кодировка пакетов Update возвращаемых в Telegram (Bot API) кодирована в UTF-8 с BOM'ом из за чего символы на русском языке отображаются адской кваказяброй а значения не пишутся в таблицу БД. Стандартные mb функции конверта utf to cp1251 (переводит) и обратно не помогли.

```
$message = $update['message']['text']; //уходить в обработчик ответов -    работает
$txt_msg = $message; // уходить в DB - не работает
$message_id = $update['message']['message_id'];
$message_name = $update['message']['chat']['first_name'];
//CREATE to DB RedBeanPHP
$user_messages = R::dispense('usermessages');
$user_messages->chat_id = $chat_id;
$user_messages->message_id = $message_id;
$user_messages->message_txt = $txt_msg;
$id = R::store($user_messages);
```

mb_convert
remote BOM не помогли

Comment: 1 ) Попробутe ка так $message = mb_convert_encoding($message, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"); 

2)У вас есть доступ к конфигу базы данных ? Параметры кодировок MySQL http://gahcep.github.io/blog/2013/01/05/mysql-utf8/ .Это чтоб в DB записывалось.

Comment: Спасибо
Не помогло/
Он декодирует в ср1251 и корректно отображает при проверке в логе (как кириллические символы) при этом в DB не пишет значения/

Доступа к конфигу нет - используется cleanDB на heroku

Comment: Удалите BOM и попробуйте так 

//Remove UTF8 Bom
function remove_utf8_bom($text)
{
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
}

И примените к тому тексту где проблема
$message = remove_utf8_bom($message);

Comment: Вообще какой либо текст перестал отображаться в логе

Comment: Код перестал выполняться после функции записи в БД

Comment: Легче вам помочь если покажите как выглядит ваш текст.И ещо проблема только  в записи в DB,Или еще где то криво отображаться?Обновите вопрос

Comment: Вот так отображается текст $txt_msq - РҐР°Р№ - при записи в лог.
При попытке записать в БД значение $message - код перестает выполняться (т.к в лог значение $message не передается)

Comment: $message = iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251', $message);
    $message = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $message);

Возвращают абракадабру РљР°Рє РґРµР»Р°?

Comment: Так должно сработать  $message = mb_convert_encoding($message, "Windows-1251", "utf-8");

Comment: Ну или так  $message = mb_convert_encoding($message, "cp1251", "utf-8");

Comment: Оба деплоя с применением обеих вариантов по очереди привели к невыполнению кода (бот переставал реагировать на вопросы) В лог сообщения не уходили

Comment: !) //уходить в обработчик ответов -    работает, 2) // уходить в DB - не работает. Так может перед тем как записывать в DB проводить эти монипуляции ?

Comment: Оба деплоя с применением обеих вариантов по очереди привели к невыполнению кода: ошибка выскакивает? , посмотрите логи .пишите поподробней ото ничего не ясно по приведенному коду

Comment: При перестановке ничего позитивного не произошло. 
Если меняется кодировка $message то ни в обработчик ни в DB ничего не уходит/
Если присваешь новой  переменной значение $message то производя декодировку меняется значение новой переменной - абракадабры нет но запись в БД не идет///

Comment: 1) "Если меняется кодировка $message то ни в обработчик ни в DB ничего не уходит ":  Как понять :запись вставляется но message пуста ? или не вставляется вообще ?

Comment: Да и  поменяй коллейшн таблицы и полей: alter table <some_table> convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: Запись имеет значение NULL. 
RBPHP автоматически выставляет коллейшн в зависимости от кодировки передаваемого значения при создании таблицы

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в кодировке на Heroku.
При на другом хосте все отлично заработало "без костылей".
В общем - Если столкнетесь с абракадаброй получая update пакеты от телеграм проверьте кодировку Вашего проекта; кодировку используемую на хосте

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй вызвать в начале скрипта

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

а потом  конвертировать

mb_convert_encoding([строка], "UTF-8", "cp1251");

Comment: Пробовал.
Он перегоняет в cp1251 но не пишет значение в DB. Интовые значения "Заходят на ура" т.е проблема не в БД.

Comment: "Интовые значения "Заходят на ура" т.е проблема не в БД" - Гениально))))

Comment: Спасибо 
Но в оценочных суждениях не нуждаюсь